# Why did the order of URL paths cause this Django bug?

Tags: python, django, django-views, url-routing

I am setting up my views in Django so that a "POST" from my homepage (index) search form will redirect either (1) to the page that the user wanted, or (2) to a results list, if that page couldn't be found. The choice is conditional on a utility function called in the index view.

Path 1 works fine. With path 2, I was getting a `Not Found: (option 2 path - what I want)` followed by `Value Error - The (option 1 view path - not what I want) didn't return an HttpResponseObject`. I fixed this bug, it seems, only by changing the order of the URL patterns in my urls.py. My question is, why would this happen if I'm not using regexs in my URLs? If my project is trying to redirect to the correct view (option 2) FIRST, why does the order of URL patterns matter? I was even getting the ValueError from the option 2 path URL.

Views:

```
def index(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = SearchForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            query = form.cleaned_data['Search']
            request.session['query'] = query
            if util.get_entry(query):
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("article", kwargs={'article': query}))
            else: 
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("search_list"))
        else:
            return render(request, 'encyclopedia/index.html', {'form': form})    
    
    else:
        form = SearchForm()
        return render(request, "encyclopedia/index.html", {
            "entries": util.list_entries(),
            "form": SearchForm(),
        })

#I don't understand why article() is involved at all in this bug, if the condition in index() routes to searchlist()
def article(request, article):
    context = {
        "article": util.get_entry(article),
        "query": request.session['query']
    }
    if util.get_entry(article) is not None:
        return render(request, "encyclopedia/article_template.html", context)
    else:
        return HttpResponseNotFound("<h1> Nope Nope Nope </h1>")

def searchlist(request):

    # Note: right now, the search bar is giving an HttpResponseNotFound. Find out why.
    # Checks pt1: We know that request.session['query'] works 
    # because we passed it in the article view successfully

    # Checks pt2: searchlist isn't getting the context properly, because it wouldn't print
    # out query when I passed that as context.

    
    query = request.session['query']
    results_list = []
    #Write a function to check if query is a substring of a list item:  
    for entry in util.list_entries():
        if re.search(query, entry):
            results_list.append(entry)
    
    context = {
        "results": results_list, 
        "query": query,
    }
    return render(request, "encyclopedia/search_list.html", context)
```

App URLs

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
    path("wiki/searchlist", views.searchlist, name='search_list'),
    path("wiki/<str:article>", views.article, name='article'),   
# Here I have switched the order of path "wiki/searchlist" and path "wiki/<str:article>" to fix this bug.
# The "article" view used to be above the "search_list" view   
]
```

Project URLs:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include("encyclopedia.urls"))
]
```

Traceback from the ValueError:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\kylea\Envs\first_app\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\kylea\Envs\first_app\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 124, in _get_response
    raise ValueError(

Exception Type: ValueError at /wiki/searchlist
Exception Value: The view encyclopedia.views.article didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.
```

Comment: please share your projects urls.py also

Comment: The URLs snippet above is from urls.py.

Comment: You are correct, I added the second urls file

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know

This is because how python works
Python is an interpreted language so it is run line by line so the first regex that matches will work.

It is better to have the most strict regex first and the most lenient one to be last.

Update: formatting and regex -> string match

Comment: Although I'm sure you're correct in general, I'm actually not using any regexs in the path or in the Util function called in my views.

Comment: what i meant to say the first string match will be used here

Comment: @KyleR the path converters like `<str:foo>`, `<int:pk>` and so on are actually internally converted to a regex by Django.

Answer (score 1):

Here your pattern with `<str:article>`, [Matches any non-empty string](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/urls/#path-converters), so this includes **"searchlist"** as well, hence path `wiki/searchlist` will get matched by `wiki/<str:article>` path also. **urlpatterns** is a **list**, so while iterating through it, django will serve the first match, here in your case `wiki/<str:article>`

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
    path("wiki/<str:article>", views.article, name='article'),
    path("wiki/searchlist", views.searchlist, name='search_list'),
]
```

So in order to match any non-empty string, except **"searchlist"** after **"wiki/"** you need to put `wiki/<str:article>` pattern after `wiki/searchlist`

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
    path("wiki/searchlist", views.searchlist, name='search_list'),
    path("wiki/<str:article>", views.article, name='article'),
]
```

Now to match `wiki/<str:article>` Django will look further down the list and `wiki/searchlist` will find its first match with `wiki/searchlist`

Comment: So I understand everything you're saying in the abstract, but do you have any ideas why this is happening when the URL is only called from an HttpResponseRedirect(reverse(""search_list"))? I thought the whole point of doing a named reverse was to override the standard path matching process?

Comment: @KyleR that occurs after that urlpatterns switching?

Comment: No, it was part of the original issue that I fixed by switching pattern order (on a lark). In my app, the search_list view is only called in a reverse from another view (so far), and never with an argument, so I'm not clear on the reason that article view could even be involved

Answer (score 0):

I came to an incomplete answer based on what Gaurav suggested (contribute if you can):
Both the path for "search_list" and "article" contained the segment "/wiki/". For some reason, the "article" path was snatching "/searchlist" from "wiki/searchlist" and passing it as the string argument to its view, even though I had used HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("search_list")).

I still need to figure out why my HttpResponseRedirect() call was hijacked by a different view.

Comment: There's no hijacking. When you use `HttpResponseRedirect` you are basically sending a response to the client (user's browser, etc.) with a 302 status code and a url. The client then makes a request to this url. There's no direct linking to a view as such